# What is "soaking wet"?

Tags: classical-latin, word-request, adjective

Is there a classical Latin adjective or other similar phrase for "soaking wet"?
I expect that I should take an adjective for "wet" and prefix it with *per-*, but I did not manage to find examples of this or more colorful expressions.
Are there attested mentions of soaking wet things in classical Latin literature?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The word you're looking for is [*madidus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dmadidus).

> **mădĭdus**, a, um, adj. madeo,
>   I.moist, wet, soaked, drenched (rare until after the Aug. per.).
>   I. Lit.
>   A. In gen.: fasciculus epistolarum aquā madidus, * Cic. *Q. Fr.* 2, 12, 4:

Compare this to [*umidus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dumidus), meaning "a little wet, damp, etc."

Comment: Thanks! I never knew *madidus* is strong enough for this use.